# How to change date format in html input type=date, from 11/22/2023 to like this November22, 2023

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, django

I am using Django framework in my project. Tried different things with input type date tag like format, scripts and jquery scripts but didnt worked.

```
  <input type="date" class="form-control-green form-control date_style"
                                id="training_date" onclick="this.showPicker()" name="training_date"
                                value="{{listing_details.training_date}}" aria-describedby="titleHelp"
                                onchange="changeEndDate(1,'')">
```

Comment: In summary: no, though someone has provided a solution using js with moment.js.  If you're going down that route then might as well implement a fully-blown datepicker.js

Comment: The solution does require JS - MDN makes this clear. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Comment: I know it mst be some custom datepicker thing, can you guys share any link I couldn't found it anywhere yet.